# Combo box getting "Enter Parameter Value" prompt when clicking a button

Tags: vba, ms-access

Any ideas why I am getting an "Enter Parameter Value" input box when running this code?

```
Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()
    Dim str As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    If IsNull(Me.Combo_1) Then
        MsgBox "Can't print an unsaved record", _
        vbOKOnly, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    str = "Combo_1 = '" & Me!Combo_1 & "'"
    Debug.Print str
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptBarCodeLabels(2)", acViewPreview, , str
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " _
    & Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Error"
End Sub
```

Edit: The button is being used to print a label of what's currently selected in Combo_1. Once the print button has been clicked, I wanted it to display the single record I chose in the label report I have it referencing. I am using Access 2003 if that means anything.

Answer (score 0):

If a field name in a query contains punctuation (Combo_1), you should enclose in brackets, like so:

```
str = "[Combo_1] = '" & Me!Combo_1 & "'"
```

The Report is expecting a parameter, but not getting it because it's not being passed through in the correct manner.

Comment: It's still giving me the same results

Comment: What's the record source for the report - is it a query?  Does the query have a field named "Combo_1" on it?

Comment: The source is a query and it does not have a field named Combo_1. Combo_1 drops down the list in column 1 on the query and then I have 2 text boxes that fills in for column 2 and 3. The combo box is unbounded so that I can use the drop down and not have it be able to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution by using some coding that was provided here: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-print-one-or-more-labels-for-a-single-access-record/

What fixed the error was most likely creating a temporary table and temporary report.